# I get the following error when I try to submit a transaction on the hyperleger playground

Tags: javascript, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

Error: Object with ID '7660' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.acme.biznet.Handset' does not exist

Comment: I am able to Add the participants and assets on the playground, but unable to submit the transaction. I keep getting the following error: Error: Object with ID '7660' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.acme.biznet.Handset' does not exist

Answer (score 0):

not enough information as to how you encounter this.

1. Is this transaction trying to update the ID field ?
2. Are you trying to update an asset (in the same transaction) that is not yet committed to the ledger ? See -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer/issues/3425 for an example
3. Have you got ACLs applied (so the participant in question cannot 'see' the asset in question due to restrictions).

Suggest to post the model and the full transaction code / sample data.

Comment: I have already created  a handset asset with id7660 successfully, but I'm now failing to commit the transaction to the ledger. When i try to submit the transaction to the ledger I get the following error? Error: Object with ID '7660' in collection with ID 'Asset:org.acme.biznet.Handset' does not exist

Comment: can you see the asset - using the id you're submitting the txn with - in Composer playground (use the identity manager, switch user).